# Bot telegram does not receive messages with media

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote a simple bot in Javascript, with App Script from Google, that needs to send me the messages it receives, via email and via chat, but I noticed that whenever the message contains media (photos, videos, audio, stickers) these seem not to be even sent to the bot, in groups but also in private chat.

Below is the code

```
const apiToken = "xxxx";

const apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + apiToken;

function doPost(e) {
  var sendMail = true;

  var webhookData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var fromUser = webhookData.message.from.id;
  var photo = webhookData.message.photo;


  if(sendMail){
    var eStringify;
    var postDataStringify;


    try{
      var eParsed = JSON.parse(e);
      eStringify = JSON.stringify(eParsed);
    }catch(ex){
      eStringify = "Error parsing e: " + ex;
    }

    try{
      var postDataParsed = JSON.parse(e.postData);
      postDataStringify = JSON.stringify(postDataParsed);
    }catch(ex){
      postDataStringify = "Error parsing postData: " + ex;
    }

    var response = "e: " + e + "\n\neStringify: " + eStringify + "\n\npostData: " + e.postData + "\n\npostDataStringify: " + postDataStringify + "\n\nwebhookData: " + JSON.stringify(webhookData);

    
    var message = {
      to: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
      subject: "Log Bot",
      body: response,
      name: "Bot"
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }

  var sendReply;
  if(photo === undefined){
   sendReply = "photo not defined";
  }else{
   sendReply = photo.toString();
  }

  var url = apiUrl + "/sendMessage?parseMode=HTML&chat_id=" + fromUser + "&text=" + sendReply;

  var opts = { muteHttpExceptions: true };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opts).getContentText();
}
```

I have already set privacy mode, but nothing changes, other messages are read correctly, how can I make the bot read the messages with media?